# Working with multiple databases?

Tags: sqlite

Using sqlite3 on Linux, how can one work with multiple databases?

I'd like to do something like the following in database 1?

```
sqlite3 database1.db
insert into database1.mytable values (select * from database2.mytable)
```

How do I write the `SELECT` query for database2 above?

Comment: are you looking for [`ATTACH DATABASE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html)?

Comment: Didn't test it yet, but I think so, thanks! Want to post your comment as reply?

Answer (score 14):

(reposting swasheck's comment as reply)

```
sqlite3 database1.db
> ATTACH DATABASE 'database2.db' AS database2;
> INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM database2.mytable;
```