# Pull Data from one database and insert to another database ( same schema )

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am currently working on moving data from one database to another in PostgreSQL. I am studying python with psycopg2 to connect and run SQL queries in one database. My problem is how can I pull and insert the data that I queried from one database to another. Most of the posts I found here talk about database from local server to a remote server. Like:

- [How to work with multiple Postgres databases in psycopg2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101609/how-to-work-with-multiple-postgres-databases-in-psycopg2/120682)

This suggests to use dblink or FDW. My situation is that both databases are in the same schema.

I am really new to this kind of task. Any suggestions?

Here's sample code in python that I am working with:

```
conn_p = p.connect("dbname='p_test' user='postgres' password='postgres' host='localhost'")
conn_t = p.connect("dbname='t_mig1' user='postgres' password='postgres' host='localhost'")

cur_p = conn_p.cursor()
cur_t = conn_t.cursor()

cur_t.execute("SELECT CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(studentnumber, ' ', '') as integer), firstname, middlename, lastname FROM sprofile")
rows = cur_t.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print "Inserting ", row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]
    cur_p.execute(""" INSERT INTO "a_recipient" (id, first_name, middle_name, last_name) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') """ % (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]))

cur_p.commit()
cur_pl.close()
cur_t.close()
```

Comment: `both databases are in the same schema`. Please clarify. And is this about a one-time transition, are repeated process or continuous replication?

Comment: apologies for the confusion. I have both db p_test and t_mig1 under public schema. I have 70 tables with 50 rows of data. Not sure what you mean by repeated process or continuous replication, I am really new to this kind of task.

Comment: Ok. it looks like both databases are in the same *cluster* in this case `localhost:5432`

Comment: does that code work?  it looks like it would?

Comment: It does. Basically, t_mig1 DB is a MySQL which I migrated to Postgresql. Problem is, the studentnumber is varchar while the id field in p_test is integer. I posted a thread on SO about this as I'm having problem with zeros. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146769/postgresql-remove-hyphens-and-whitespaces/50146850#50146850

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FDW and dblink have the advantage that they make a direct postgreql to postgresql connection which means that there will be no processing needed in your python code.  here's an example that should work much like your example code, except faster.

```
conn_p = p.connect("dbname='p_test' user='postgres' password='postgres' host='localhost'")
strt="dbname='t_mig1' user='postgres' password='postgres' host='localhost'"
cur_p = conn_p.cursor();

cur_p.execute("select dblink_connect('tmpdb',%s);",(strt,));
cur_p.execute("""
  insert into "a_recipient" (id, first_name, middle_name, last_name)
  SELECT * FROM dblink('tmpdb',
    $$
    SELECT CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(studentnumber, '[^0-9]', '','g') as integer), firstname, middlename, lastname FROM sprofile 
    $$ ) as x( a int,b text, c text,d text);
""");

cur_p.execute("SELECT dblink_disconnect('tmpdb');");
```

unfortunately I was not able to test this code. feel free to make any correction needed.
I also changed the regex to remove all non digits.

Comment: I will test this code Sir. Thank you. I haven't played with dblink but I read it a while ago. I think we need also to install the contrib in the server where our production db is located before I can use it. Right now, I am just testing in my local machine.

Comment: yeah, youll need contrib, and possibly `create extension dblink;`

Comment: Noted Sir. Question though about my code, will I get bottleneck with the execute() in my for loop?

Comment: probably your code will be faster than disk, it is hard to guess. the large number of inserts could be performace problem for postgresql.