# sqlite: attached database doesn't work properly

Tags: sqlite

1) I can open database from the command line:

```
bash-3.2 # sqlite3 RecordingDb.sqlite
SQLite version 3.16.2 2017-01-06 16:32:41
Enter ".help" for usage hints.

sqlite> .databases
main: /db/RecordingDb.sqlite

sqlite> select * from recording limit 1;
|110|4||1423222200|1423049398|1423051200|0|0||0|100|||0|0||||1013760|1|11|4|19300||4|4|1801|||4||0|0||||20486|||
```

2) I can attach it from the sqlite prompt, but it doesn't work properly:

```
bash-3.2 # sqlite3
SQLite version 3.16.2 2017-01-06 16:32:41
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.

sqlite> attach database 'RecordingDB.sqlite' as RecordingDb;

sqlite> .databases
main: 
RecordingDb: /db/RecordingDB.sqlite

sqlite> select * from RecordingDb.recording limit 1;
Error: no such table: RecordingDb.recording
```

Why?

Similar question:

[Working with multiple databases?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25127/working-with-multiple-databases/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux has case sensitive file names.

```
       main: /db/RecordingDb.sqlite
RecordingDb: /db/RecordingDB.sqlite
                           ^
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I remember this case, and you're right: my mistake was the root cause.